# Firestore security for game where users do not have account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am confused on the insistence in the documentation to have users sign on to give authentication.  With a card game app, I want users to get on easily (without a need to sign on), find a game to play in, and play the game. As cards are played, each turn is recorded in Firestore, and all users notified to read the changed parameters. So all users can read, write and update.
Even if I did make users sign on, anyone could create an account, and I would be no further ahead except I have turned away some game participants.
I know I can set rules so that all data is a small size. I maybe check to ensure no data is stored after a certain time without being used, and I could delete the collection for that game. Is is it this sort of procedures I use to guard the database from growing too big, or a 'bad' user working out where the data is, and overwriting data for some games.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a low-friction way to get users signed in, use [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).  It will give the user an account with a UID without requiring any prompts.  You can then use security rules to protect per-user information, since anonymous accounts have a UID just like normal accounts.  You can then decide to let the user [upgrade that account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account) when they want a more permanent identity in your game (since anonymous accounts become inaccessible if the user clears their device local storage).